# SqlDataReader Timeout expired odd error

Tags: .net, sql-server, database-connection, connection-pooling, sqldatareader

Been fighting an aggravating bug with SqlDataReader.  This old code is in Visual Basic using .NET Framework 3.5 on an AWS server running Windows Server 2012.  Database is Msft Sql Server running in Amazon's RDS environment.

We started seeing this error in our log:
*"Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding."*
and the last entry in the error stack is:
*at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()*

Here is the code where the error occurs in our db wrapper.

```
Try
   Using connection As New SqlConnection(dbConnStr)
      connection.Open()
         Using command As New SqlCommand(sql, connection)
            Using dataReader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
               Do While dataReader.Read()
                  'do stuff with the results here
               Loop
             End Using
      End Using
   End Using
Catch
   'write error to log here
End Try
```

- The database behind this system is definitely being worked.  I ran a trace and see tons of queries being called.  Also ran a trace with a
  filter to only show queries about 5 secs, and there are none.
- The queries that trigger the error are random, never the same.  And when I see the error I can grab the query from the logs and run it
  manually, and it runs quickly/successfully.
- The trace also indicates that the query is never run in the database.
- Since we are running in AWS, we spun up another server and restored our AMI to it, and got same problem.
- After the errors start to accumulate, our connection pool blows up.  Our connection pool is set at 700.  We did add this Connection
  Lifetime=30 to our connection string, and that keeps the pool down
  around 100.
- I'll see thousands of queries run successfully between errors.
- Windows and .NET are both patched up to date.

I stuck some extra logging in, and one thing I learned was the connection.state = Open just before the call to ExecuteReader, and Closed just after when the error occurs.

To mitigate the problem I built in some retry logic.  If ExecuteReader does not run, I bail out, wait one second, then call it all again.  This works every time, but introduces a 30 second delay.  I could probably bump the commandTimeout down to something less annoying than 30 secs, but I'm really interested in why the error is occurring in the first place.

One thing I have decided is connection pool handling is art rather than science.  In this case our conclusion is the connection to the database has somehow become corrupt.  We surmise the new Connection Lifetime setting helps recycle the pool and keeps it from blowing up, which is nice because it prevents this website from going down.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This uses a very simple implementation of ADO and as you've rightly identified, it's not really handling connection pooling, connection state etc very well at times.

It sounds like if heavy workload or errors are accumulating, it's failing to close connections properly. (this should happen when your "using" statement completes and disposes).  You could have a read up on adding more error/retry handling around failures, closing and then re-opening failed connection states etc.

The easiest solution though would probably be implementing an ORM (personally I like Dapper, but choose whatever suits you best) to handle all of this stuff for you - it'll likely be a lot better and easier than trying to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I've used Dapper in other projects, also a fan.  But in this case it would just push the error down into that code, wouldn't help.  Dapper also does an ExecuteReader on an open Connection:
            {
                return cmd.ExecuteReader(GetBehavior(wasClosed, behavior));
            }

Comment: Personally I'd be inclined to try, but either way a good first step could be to implement connection Disposal and/or state reset in your catch statement.